# Radio button , both buttons are getting selected

Tags: html, angular, button, radio-button

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>username</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>email</label>
        <br />
        <input type="email" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>secret question</label>
        <br />
        <select type="radio" class="form-control">
          <option value="pet">your fav. pet?</option>
          <option value="teacher">your fav. teacher?</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p style="margin: 10px">your reply:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="radio" *ngFor ="let gender of genders">
        <label> <input type="radio" [value]="gender" />{{ gender }} </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

here in div class="radio" I am passing a string array which contains 2 value 'male' and 'female'. Expected behavior should be once male selected female should get UN-selected and vice versa. But I don't know why I am able to select both male and female radio button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an attribute name on your input

```
<input type="radio" [value]="gender" name="gender" />{{ gender }}
```

Comment: it resolved the issue thank you @FolabiAhn, could tell me why it happened though? And how adding name attribute resolve the problem?

Comment: @cha1nsaw Radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group. By belonging to the same group that forces just one radio button of the group to be checked.

Comment: don't forget to mark it answered ;)